# "NullPointerException: Location is required." when running the JavaFX project JAR, but not when running from the IDE

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

I have a JavaFX project. It is running fine from within the IDEA. But when I export it as **Runnable JAR** and try running it from the command line usin gcommand `java -jar MYJavaFXProject.jar` it gives following error : `java.lang.NullPointerException: Location is required`.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Location is required.
     at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3207)
     at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3175)
     at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3148)
     at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3124)
     at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3104)
     at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:3097)
     at application.Main.start(Main.java:16)
     at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$161(LauncherImpl.java:863)
     at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$174(PlatformImpl.java:326)
     at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$172(PlatformImpl.java:295)
     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
     at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$173(PlatformImpl.java:294)
     at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
     at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
     at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$147(WinApplication.java:177)
     at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Earlier I had come across this same issue while runnning it from Eclipse, but that seemed to be valid location issue and got resolved after I corrected the path.

Below is the line number 16 of Main.java file :

```
Object root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("Sample.fxml"));
```

and **Main.java file :**

```
public class Main extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        try {
            Object root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("Sample.fxml"));
            Scene scene = new Scene((Parent) root,1400,800);
            scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("application.css").toExternalForm());
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.show();
            primaryStage.setResizable(false);
            primaryStage.setHeight(820);
            primaryStage.setWidth(1330);

        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

My **Main.java** and **Sample.fxml** files both are in the same package.

**EDIT 1 START**

[image]

**EDIT 1 END**

**EDIT 2 START**

I had also confirmed  that the Sample.fxml is present in the final packaged jar file.I executed below command :

```
C:\Users\Asif\Desktop>jar -tf MyJavaFXTool.jar | find "Sample.fxml"
```

which returned `src/application/Sample.fxml`. So this confirms that the Sample.fxml file is present in the JAR.

**EDIT 2 END**

I looked up over the internet and couldn't find any helpful resource.

Comment: your description is conterdictory: once you load "/application/Sample.fxml" and then in code it's "Sample.fxml" ... problems like this are mostly related to a) the resource isn't where you expect it is or b) there's a spelling error Please triple check (there's nothing obviously wrong) spelling, package, actual code, existence of resource in the jar ..

Comment: Yes as @kleopatra said, the resource path is wrong. I'm sure you will find the answer on Stackoverflow if you search for "intellij resource". I had the same problem some time ago and I'm pretty sure I found the solution on this site.

Comment: It depends on the project layout, it is possible that if you put non *.java file in the _source_ dir the IDE compiler will not deploy them into the _binary_ dir. So you should check how idea filters the resources.

Comment: @kleopatra Please ignore the "application/Sample.fxml" line.That was a typo. I have edited my post. My Sample.fxml file is in the application package. But I haven't mentioned application path while loading resource. Actual code is the Main.java file that I have provided. My Main.java and Sample.fxml are all in the same package i.e. application. Whether I write "application/Sample.fxml" or just "Sample.fxml" it still throws error.. I will try to upload the image of my project structure as displayed in Eclipse. Thanks for your response.But I am not sure how to resolve my issue.

Comment: @Axel I have updated my post.

Comment: @minus Main.java and Sample.fxml werre created by default under the application package of src folder by Eclipse IDE. I have another JavaFX project whose JAR runs fine. Not sure what is wrong with this particular project. I am just stuck.

Comment: Someone correct me if I'm wrong but doesnt `getClass().getResource(...)` check the resource folder which you fxml is clearly not in try moving it into your resources folder let me know the result

Comment: _src/application/Sample.fxml. So this confirms that the Sample.fxml file is present in the JAR_ actually, it only confirms that something is very fishy: it shouldn't be under _src_ but in the compiled package _/application/Sample.fxml_. Open the jar with an arbitrary zip tool and check if it is ..., that is a sister of _/application/Main.class_

Answer (score 0):

If you use *maven* to build your jar you may need to add and configure the resource plugin.

This is and example of configuration using a default maven layout.

```
    <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.7</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>copy-fxml-resources</id>
                <!-- here the phase you need -->
                <phase>validate</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <outputDirectory>${basedir}/target/classes/</outputDirectory>
                    <resources>
                        <resource>
                            <directory>src/main/java/</directory>
                            <filtering>false</filtering>
                            <includes>
                                <include>**/*.fxml</include>
                                <include>**/*.css</include>
                            </includes>
                        </resource>
                    </resources>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
```

Maven will not copy your resources if they are not in the `src/main/resources/` folder, so you have use the `maven-resources-plugin` to select which files you want to copy from the source folder to the bin folder.

I had more or less the same problem because *SceneBuilder* does not fully understand the maven layout, so I had to put fxml and css in the same folder of java files.